# Using a reference list to find specific files by name

Tags: python, csv, search, pandas, glob

I have list of file names extracted from a csv stored in a variable, that I want to search for within a certain directory, see extraction of this list to variable names filenames below. If found I want perform a certain operation on the matched files one by one.

```
#Python 3.5, Pandas 0.17.1
#Reading in list with characteristics of files
index = pd.read_csv('INDEX.csv',usecols = ['Filenumber','Province'])
#Automating extraction of column filename on basis of province and full rows
province = index[index.Province == 'MG']
filenames = province['Filenumber']
```

So far I have not found any solution to this problem. I am new to Python and would therefore greatly appreciate any push in the right direction be it in the form of a solution or reference material to read up on these types of operations.

In summary:

With the variable filenames which has the names of the files (minus the file type (.csv)), I want to find  files with these names in one directory/folder. And after that (or during the search for the files) perform  a certain operation on each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import os

filenames =['testfile1','testfile2']

for file in filenames:
    if os.path.isfile(file+'.csv'):
        print "File "+ file + ".csv exists."
    else:
        print "File "+ file + ".csv does not exist."
```

Edit: The following is for python 3.x (untested, since I have none):

```
import os

filenames =['testfile1.csv','testfile2.csv']

for file in filenames:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        print("File exists.")
    else:
        print("File does not exist.")
```

Comment: This results in the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\code.py", line 35, in <module>
    if os.path.isfile(file +'.csv'):
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: Sorry, I am working on Python 2.7, have not seen that you seem to work on python 3.x. You will have to adapt print commands and string operations to python 3.7. I have attached an easier version above which should work in 3.7

Comment: Was able to get that working. The main problem here was that in my original code the variable filename did not contain the actual filename as a string. I was not able to use the syntax described in your solution. However converting the names in filename to strings and adding '.csv' resulted in being able to make the code work. As such: filenames = province['Filenumber'].astype(str) + '.csv'. Then using your solution. Help greatly appreciated.